# How do I get the dropdown value of the html select using jquery rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, haml

HAML File:

```
 = form_for '', :remote => true do |f|
   = f.select :stp_name, @steps
```

JS:

```
  title = $('#stp_id').val()
  console.log title
```

The console always returns "undefined". I have tried solutions to other answers, but none of them seem to work.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an identifier to your `select` tag, an id or class, then using jQuery use `val`, to get the selected value. Note the way to add an `id` to a Rails `select` helper, the `html_options` must be as the fourth argument:

```
= f.select :stp_name, @steps, {}, id: 'select'
```

Then `$('#select').val()` will give you the value.